# Disable clear at start of screen via .screenrc?

Tags: mac-osx, xterm, gnu-screen

Is there any way to disable the behavior of gnu-screen, of issuing a clear at startup?

I'm using screen merely as a backstop, so that if disconnected, the session isn't HUP'ed. And I've got my shell (bash) config'd to "exec screen -A" on login, so that I get right into screen automatically.

However, screen immediately issues a clear and then I've got to scroll back up to see whatever login messages there might have been.

Similarly, at exit, I'd like to skip the clear there too, so I can see the results of my .bash_logout.

(If it's any help, my term is usually xterm-color (via Mac OS X's Terminal.app) though I do sometimes come in via ssh from some other node. And I'm generally connecting to an Ubuntu box/instance.)

Answer (score 1):

Because `screen` takes over the entire screen, its not possible to have it leave the terminal buffer unprocessed.  If you're interested in the `motd` specifically, you can always have your .bash_profile call `cat /etc/motd`, which would give you the same functionality.

Another option is to just call `screen` manually, which sounds like it might be the behaviour you want anyway--since you're not actively using the screens to do work.  This is even further recommended if you're worried about having a compromised account--since the login screen also shows your last login location.

Comment: I *do* want screen to run automatically - so I don't have to remember to do so -- probably right *after* I get disconnected and remember I haven't. :/

Comment: I'm already using "termcapinfo xterm*|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@" (in .screenrc) to capture everything via my terminal buffer (vs. screen's), so I'm close; I just want to skip the clear at startup (and exit).

Comment: BTW: Using screen seems the only way to *automatically* keep sessions active in case of disconnect - though I'm happy to be proven wrong here. This is the primary functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: You can `nohup` and background the command, but once you logout with the session, you will never be able to bring it to the foreground, so make sure you pipe output to a file to be read later.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Redmumba, `screen` takes over the entire terminal so you can't have it take over the existing buffer and display.

What I have done is changed my `.screenrc` to display a status bar at the bottom of the terminal window, and trained my fingers to say `screen -ADR` if I don't see that status bar.  That way you have a visual cue that you are in fact running `screen`, and a reflex that will start it for you before you start to do anything which might not survive accidental disconnecting.

(Also, if you have the current time being displayed in the screen status bar, this acts as a keep-alive signal that can prevent connections from disconnecting due to being idle too long.)

Comment: Right; I don't want it to take over the existing buffer - I'd actually prefer it do nothing at all to the buffer/display. :)

Comment: I appreciate the other suggestions - though of course a fully automatic method is preferable.

Comment: Perhaps screen isn't the right tool for what I'm looking for; I just want something that will *by default* leave my session open if there's a disconnection, so I can pick up where I left off.